# Httpclient library login

Tags: java, httpclient

Suppore i want to login here: http://www.vodafone.it/190/trilogy/jsp/home.do and i use the code:

```
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.vodafone.it/190/trilogy/jsp/home.do");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
    List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
    //Visito la pagina del Login
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://www.vodafone.it/190/trilogy/jsp/login.do");

    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", ""));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", ""));

    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

    response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
    entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
    cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

If it's correct,how i can know if i'm logged in?

Comment: I am no httpclient expert but you can fetch the url of the page you are redirected to once you are logged in or not logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways this can be found out. (None of them are standard. Check what applies to you.)

1. Generally after successful login, web sites `redirect` the users to some home page. If the login is unsuccessful then this redirect does not happen as you are back on login page. So if the http status code returned is  303 or 307 then you can assume that your login was successful. You can verify this using your browser with some browser add-on (like FireBug in Firefox).
2. If the above case is not true (meaning there are no redirects), then you will be on home page directly. In that case you can check some basic contents of the page(which generally indicate what the page is all about). Page header is one way which you can read to make sure you are on your home page.

Comment: In case 2, you may also look for the presence of a logout button/link as opposed of a login one.